# Parsing problems with datetime

Tags: java, android, datetime

for diffInSec=10 it returns
01:00:10

I want just to get 00:00:10
I do not know where is that 1 hour comes from.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
t.setText(sdf1.format(new Date(diffInSec*1000))+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing new Date(diffInSec*1000); gives you a date object that corresponds to 10 seconds after the epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). When you're using the SimpleDateFormat, it's converting it from GMT to your local time zone (for me, doing `sdf1.format(new Date(diffInSec*1000))` gives me 19:00:10 since I'm in GMT -5)